# Wake on LAN on Linux

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, wake-on-lan

I just learned that I could wake my Macbook Air 2012 from sleep over the LAN under OS X.  However, I can't make it work under Linux with the [method described on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN).  Has anyone managed to do it on Linux?

Comment: Please add a link to the Arch Wiki and the Linux flavor in use! Also: one Arch wiki mentions: wireless cards do not support Wake-on-LAN

Comment: You are running Linux on the MacBook, I assume?

Comment: @patrix, yes.---

Comment: Maybe this might me helpful... https://laufer.tumblr.com/post/649059550/wol-mac-mini